# Using all elements in an array except for one

Tags: java

sorry for the bad title I couldn´t come up with anything better.

I want this to see if the array `part[]` have any elements that are 0. But i dont want it to check `part[0]`.

```
if(Integer.parseInt(part[]) == 0)
```

So basiclly if i could do something like

```
if(Integer.parseInt(part[!=0]) == 0)
```

or

```
if(Integer.parseInt(part[<0]) == 0)
```

But obviously that wont work

Comment: have you tried loops like: for(int i=1;i<part.length;i++{}

Comment: `for(int i = 1; i < part.length; i++) { if(Integer.parseInt(part[i]) == 0) { ... } }`

Answer (score 3):

To check if the array has any element with a value of 0, without checking the first index of the array, you could do:

```
boolean hasZero = false;
for (int i = 1; i < array.length(); i++) {
    if (array[i] == 0) {
        hasZero = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Using the `Stream` api, it could be:

```
boolean hasZero = Arrays.stream(array).skip(1).anyMatch(i->i==0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you won't modify the array, you can create a copy of a range using Arrays.copyOfRange(int[] original, int from, int to):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public static void main(String args[])
{
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    fun(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 2, arr.length), 3);
}

public static void fun(int a[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8 you can use a stream.

```
if (IntStream.range(1, part.length).anyMatch(i -> Integer.parseInt(part[i])==0)) {
    // do stuff
}
```